# Как програмно изменить цвет текста отключенного EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Имеется отключенное (`android:enabled="false"`) поле ввода `EditText`.
Необходимо программно (через код Java) изменить цвет заранее введенного текста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, следует использовать метод setTextColor.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int)

Методы класса Color помогут задать любой цвет (который в android храниться в типе int).

Например:

```
edit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#336699"));
```

Comment: Странно, но это работает. Я думал, что при отключении элемента на него "поверх" добавляется стиль, т.е. после любой установки setTextColor текст был бы немного сероватый.